# How to store null in Perl hash

Tags: perl, xs

I want to use Perl hash in my C code (XS) as a set, so I only need to keep keys in hash. Is it possible to store something like null or another constant value to avoid creating unnecessary value?

Something like this:

```
int add_value(HV *hash, SV *value)
{
    // just an example of key
    char key[64];
    sprintf(key, "%p", value);
    if (hv_exists(hash, key, strlen(key)) return 0;

    // here I need something instead of ?
    return hv_stores(hash, key, ?) != NULL;
}
```

One of possible solution could be to store value itself, but maybe there is special constant for `undef` or null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&PL_sv_undef` is *the* undef scalar. It's read-only. You probably want *a* fresh undef scalar, as created using `newSV(0)`<sup>[1]</sup>.

The scalar returned by `newSV(0)` starts with a refcount of one, of which the hash "takes possession" when the scalar is stored in it using `hv_stores`, so don't `SvREFCNT_dec` or `sv_2mortal` the returned scalar. (Do increase the reference count if you store it elsewhere too.)

---

1. ```
   # "The" undef (A specific read-only variable that will never get deallocated)
   $ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'Dump(undef)'
   SV = NULL(0x0) at 0x3596700
     REFCNT = 2147483641
     FLAGS = (READONLY,PROTECT)

   # "An" undef (It's not the type of SVt_NULL that make it undef...)
   $ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'Dump($x)'
   SV = NULL(0x0) at 0x1bb7880
     REFCNT = 1
     FLAGS = ()

   # Another undef (... It's the lack of "OK" flags that make it undef)
   $ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'$x="abc"; $x=undef; Dump($x)'
   SV = PV(0x3d5f360) at 0x3d86590
     REFCNT = 1
     FLAGS = ()
     PV = 0
   ```

Comment: So I have to release it manually before releasing hash with `hv_undef()`?

Comment: No, as part of clearing a hash, the refcount of the scalars therein will get decremented.

Comment: You should never have to use `undef(%hash)` aka `hv_undef(hv)`. You probably want `%hash=()` aka `hv_clear(hv)` on the rare occasion that you want to empty the hash.

Comment: yes; either you intend to use the hash again, in which case hv_undef will clear some things (I believe) that then will just have to be reallocated, or you don't, in which case you should be freeing the hash, not undefing it.

Answer (score 5):

`&PL_sv_undef` is the undefined value, but you can't, unfortunately, use it naively in hashes and arrays.  Quoting [perlguts](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html#AVs%2c-HVs-and-undefined-values):

*Generally, if you want to store an undefined value in an AV or HV, you should not use &PL_sv_undef , but rather create a new undefined value using the newSV function, for example:*

```
av_store( av, 42, newSV(0) );
hv_store( hv, "foo", 3, newSV(0), 0 );
```